# WebRTC connection doesn't send audio samples through audio channel yet there is data being sent

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I currently have two peers set to send audio through WebRTC (code is made to later support more users that dynamically change, so it's in a class, but otherwise should be normal), and although they DO connect, and DO send their track information, there is no received audio on either end. I run the getStats() as per documentation and got results that I don't understand:

```
ID: RTCInboundRTPAudioStream_3738623979
Timestamp: 1624090959263.524
ssrc: 3738623979
kind: audio
trackId: RTCMediaStreamTrack_receiver_1
transportId: RTCTransport_0_1
codecId: RTCCodec_0_Inbound_111
mediaType: audio
jitter: 0.001
packetsLost: 0
remoteId: RTCRemoteOutboundRTPAudioStream_3738623979
packetsReceived: 22142
fecPacketsReceived: 0
fecPacketsDiscarded: 0
bytesReceived: 1664520  <---
headerBytesReceived: 631982
lastPacketReceivedTimestamp: 1624090959262
jitterBufferDelay: 0
jitterBufferEmittedCount: 0
totalSamplesReceived: 0  <---
concealedSamples: 0
silentConcealedSamples: 0
concealmentEvents: 0
insertedSamplesForDeceleration: 0
removedSamplesForAcceleration: 0
audioLevel: 0  <---
totalAudioEnergy: 0
totalSamplesDuration: 0
```

There is no audio (audioLevel: 0), no received samples (totalSamplesReceived: 0), but there are bytes being received (at about 29kbps so I believe less than should be used by that codec which is:

```
ID: RTCCodec_0_Inbound_111
Timestamp: 1624092364725.83
transportId: RTCTransport_0_1
payloadType: 111
mimeType: audio/opus
clockRate: 48000
channels: 2
sdpFmtpLine: minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
```

which according to a google search should be [~52kbps)](https://flashphoner.com/opus-codec-bitrate-webrtc-call/)

Receiver and sender tracks are both not 'muted' and they are 'enabled'.

Wireshark detects seemingly random bits being sent between the ports (the whole thing runs now on localhost in two browsers) at expected rate (~110 bits per packet) so PROBABLY the audio is sent just not correctly received.

My code closely matches the one used here https://webrtc.org/getting-started/remote-streams (except, of course, for it being in a class).
I tried both setting the stream in addTrack like this: `peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream)` and omitting it (`peerConnection.addTrack(track)`).

Same results in Brave (chromium) and Firefox.

Comment: Are you following just that single tutorial? Have you established a good connection between the peers? The bits you see are  probably because the tracks are being sent, but they won't play until the connection is complete. Focus on the connection itself and less on the tracks